# react-native can't run in a real devices but when I use the VPN it work! why is that?

Tags: android, vpn, react-native

react-native can't run in a real devices but when I ***use the VPN it work***! why is that?

Comment: the VPN is working on pc

Comment: how did you solve this @ElexiUric?

Comment: I have the same problem, did you solved this??

Comment: Has anyone find out a way to work over this? Appreciate your comment

Answer (score 0):

The VPN is possibly blocking access to packager  which is running on port 8081 on your desktop. See if you can whitelist that in your vpn settings